# Show ArrayAdapter when TextView is clicked

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-adapterview

As we know that we can set ArrayAdapter to the Spinner or to ListView to populate data into these views.

In my app testView is there. I want to populate item of an arrayAdapter just below to TestView when TextView is clicked.

Please find the images:-
In the Image if user will tap on 4 Selected then it show the list.

If user tap on other parts of the screen then list will gone.

[image]
[image]

In my app user will able to send message. Before sending message user needs to select people to whom he wants to send message from list(as shown in above image).

Suppose he select 5 people then on the top it will show "5 Selected" and when he clicks on "5 Selected" then I need to show selected person on top of the screen and when user tap some where else on the screen then the list will disappear.

Problem with expandable list view is when it expand then it expand on same screen but I want it will expand on top of the screen which will not disturb other views like spinner dropdown.

Comment: Use a expandable listview instead

Comment: You need to use is [DropDown](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) and use it with custom adapter and AppCompat style

Comment: @kgandroid ... expandable listview is not a solution. When user click on remaining part of the screen then list need to disappear but in expandable listview we can not do like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

non of the above works for me. Any way thank you members for your time.

I achieve this by using AlerDialog and I put it on top.

```
public void showSelectedPeople(View v) {
    ArrayList<String> aListNoOfSelection = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (rows != null) {
        for (PostOptionsRow postOptionsRow : rows) {
            if (postOptionsRow.getType() == PostOptionsRow.TYPE_GROUP
                    && !postOptionsRow.hasChildren()
                    && postOptionsRow.isSelected()) {
                aListNoOfSelection.add(postOptionsRow.getTitle());
            } else if (postOptionsRow.getType() == PostOptionsRow.TYPE_GROUP
                    && postOptionsRow.hasChildren()
                    && postOptionsRow.getChildren() != null) {
                for (PostOptionsRow postOptionsRowInner : postOptionsRow
                        .getChildren()) {
                    if (postOptionsRowInner.isSelected()) {
                        aListNoOfSelection.add(postOptionsRowInner
                                .getTitle());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    aAdapterNoOfSelection = new NoOfSelectionAdapter(context, 0, aListNoOfSelection);

    if (aListNoOfSelection.size() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Please select a recipient for this post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    ListView listView = new ListView(this);
    listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    listView.setAdapter(aAdapterNoOfSelection);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(listView);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    wmlp.x = 55; // x position
    wmlp.y = 25; // y position

    dialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the current expanded group position stored in a variable. In onGroupExpanded do the following.

private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;
private ExpandableListView lv; //your expandable listview
...

lv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

```
@Override
public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
            lv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
        }
        lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
}
```

});

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int i, long l) {

            String dis_name = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (i>=1) {
                Dis_list.remove(" ");

            } 

        }



    });
```

and again  Dis_list.set(0," ") when dropdown  disappears

Comment: @vaibhav...NO this code is not working...I want to populate like spinner dropdown... and once you will tap on other part of the screen then dropdown will disappear...

Comment: let me check if i got your question : lets consider we are using expandablelistview itself , So what you want is when you select something from spinner . the expandablelistview must show that item only and again with that expandable listview you want to expand only current item .. Rite ???

Comment: @vaibhav...Thanks for your time and interest...
I updated my question. Please have a look..

Comment: i am not getting what you want to do as far as screen overlapping issue can be solved by using spinner as listview item

Comment: if I will use list view then it will show the list on same screen not on the top of the screen and if I will use spinner then by default one item will selected on the spinner. I not want to show any item. When user will click (5 Selected) then only it will show the name of the selected person.
Now you got why I am not able to use spinner or list view

Comment: insert blank thing in spinner and remove it on the tap of your spinner. so by default you wont be having anything at the first time

Comment: setOnItemSelectedListener is used in it ... remove the blank item from the array itself when user clicks it for the first time

Comment: Hi vaibhav...Will you send code to me ... because I am able to hide item on top of dropdown but it need to again appear when dropdown will disappear ....and this is not working...